# Cannot Kill These Mutations - Java Junit Pit Testing

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, mutation

I have a simple method that tests whether a calculated difference is within a range. It's showing 5 mutations for the returned value. No matter what I try, I cannot kill these mutations. Below is the method and the test case.

```
    public boolean isInRange(Float value1, Float value2) {
        int upperBound = acceptableDifference;
        int lowerBound = -acceptableDifference;
        Float difference = value1 - value2;
        return difference >= lowerBound && difference <= upperBound;
    }

////////TEST CASE

        assertEquals(true, classUnderTest.isInRange(20.0F, 30.0F));
        assertEquals(false, classUnderTest.isInRange(20.0F, 45.0F));
```

How do you kill mutations such as this?

The PIT Report:

```
96      public boolean isInRange(Long value1, Long value2) { 
97          int upperBound = acceptableDifference;
98  1       int lowerBound = -acceptableDifference;   //<== One mutation
99  1       Long difference = value1 - value2;        //<== One mutation
100 5       return difference >= lowerBound && difference <= upperBound;  //<== Five Mutations
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the correct code and what is the mutation you are doing?

Comment: Sure. So, the biggest mutation I want to kill is the return statement (there are 5 for that line alone). I have tried supplying values that cause that method to return both true and false and then used assertEquals() to verify that either true or false was correctly returned. The mutations are not killed, however. As you can see in the PIT report, line 100 has 5 mutations. (it removes the conditional boundaries).

Comment: To kill this mutation you need to run a test that will check the boundaries. How do you set the acceptableDifference?

Comment: It's pulled as an environment variable. For right now, I'm using PowerMockito to mock the environment variables.

Comment: So it's hard to tell you how to kill this mutations. What you need to do is to write a test that check the boundary in the return statement. For example if the acceptableDifference is 5 you need to write a test with 
    
    value 1 - value 2 = 5

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I have already tried that. I have set acceptableDifference = 10.0      and then did the test cases:   assertEquals(true, classUnderTest.isInRange(20.0F, 30.0F)); <==should return true
assertEquals(false, classUnderTest.isInRange(20.0F, 45.0F)); <==should return false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189900/discussion-between-shaked-eyal-and-marcus-holden).

Comment: Unfortunately, my company places a restriction on that. So, I will have to continue trying to do this solo. I appreciate the input.

Comment: And if you do the mutation and remove the boundaries the test should fail. Does it?

Comment: got it. I had to also account for negative as well as positive values in the testing. dumb oversight. Thank.s